# Firefox 88+: use FileZilla when encountering ftp:// URI

Tags: firefox, ftp, filezilla

- Ubuntu 20.10
- Firefox 88.0 (apt install)
- FileZilla client 3.53.1 (flatpak install)

The ftp protocol handling is being removed from Firefox.  By default, it is turned off in 88.0, and is scheduled to be removed completely in 90.

How can I set Firefox's application handler for ftp:// URIs to open filezilla?

FF->Preferences->Applications->ftp

I've tried pointing it to:

```
/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.filezillaproject.Filezilla/current/active/files/bin/filezilla
```

which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove FileZilla Flatpak and use deb-package instead by:

```
flatpak remove org.filezillaproject.Filezill

sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

and then associate it with *ftp://*.